# Fit GAMs with minimum constraints

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, constrained-regression

I have a two-dimensional predictor plane, 0-1-Observations and a priori knowledge of minimal probabilities per combination of the predictors. I would like to fit a model (e.g. GAM from the mgcv package) that yields predictions that lie above the minimal values.

The problem is how to specify the model. The following is a toy example where the minimal probability is 0.5.

```
rm(list=ls())
require(mgcv)
set.seed(1)
l<-1000
x<-seq(0,1,l=l)
p<-0.5
y<-as.numeric(runif(length(x))<1-x^4)

df<-data.frame(x=x,y=y,min=p)
m1<-gam(y~s(x)+min,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=df)
predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(x=1,min=0.5),type="response")
```

I found that offset does not help.

Subtracting the minimal probability from the response does not help as this yields negative responses which do not make sense.

How can I adapt the model to accomodate for the given minimal value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was using the pcls function in the mgcv-package to alter the coefficients of the first fit to match the side constraints. Ignore the linear equality constraints and only apply inequality constraints. (The following example closely follows the one in the help to the pcls function.

```
require(mgcv)
x<-seq(0,2*pi,l=100)
y<-sin(x)+rnorm(length(x),sd=0.1)
m31<-gam(y~s(x),fit=FALSE)
m32<-gam(G=m31)
m33<-m32
M<-model.matrix(m32)
m31$Ain<-M
m31$bin<-c(rep(0,nrow(M)))
m31$sp<-m32$sp
m31$off<-m31$off-1
m31$p<-c(1,rep(0,ncol(M)-1))
m31$C<-matrix(NA,0,0)
p<-pcls(m31)
m32$coefficients<-p
plot(x,y)
lines(x,predict(m32,type="response",newdata=data.frame(x=x)),col=2)
lines(x,predict(m33,type="response",newdata=data.frame(x=x)),col=4)
```